# Downloading remote files using the Javascript file API

Tags: javascript, access-control, fileapi

Stemming from a lack of finding a download manager I like on Ubuntu, I was wondering if it's possible to create one using HTML5 and JavaScript with the new File API available in Chrome. At the moment I'm working on a proof of concept which will just download a small file (Google's logo) from a remote URL into the sandbox file system. Code below:

```
window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

function onError(e) {
    console.log('Error:', e)
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {

    window.requestFileSystem(TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {

        fs.root.getFile('google.png', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {

                var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'image/png'});

                writer.write(blob);

            }, onError);

        }, onError);

    }, onError);

}

xhr.send();
```

This seems like it'd work to me, however when running it won't allow me to download Google's logo due to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Due to this being relatively new I haven't been able to find the *best* way to achieve what I want using the new file API functions, so I'm not even sure if using a AJAX request is the best way to do it. If not, I'm open to suggestions. Otherwise, is there a way to get around the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` problem?

I need to keep this 100% client side also, I can't use something like PHP to stream the file to the client or anything.

Answer (score 1):

[`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) only works in current domain, unless you use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Since you have no control over Google's server, you can't use it, so yo can't access Google's files from your domain.

Of course, you could always use `XMLHttpRequest` to get a file from your server, which connects to Google and outputs the desired file.

Comment: Also see [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: Okay, so using an AJAX request is out then, since I can't rely on the domain allowing me to use it and I can't have a server side solution either. Is there any other way I can download the file to Chrome's sandbox storage without using AJAX?

Comment: @ChrisWhite In order to save anything to Chrome's storage, you must have the data you want to save. And if that data comes from a file in a server, you must use AJAX to get it.